# How to setup deja-up (backup) with "copy" cloud service?

Tags: cloud, deja-dup

I have ubuntu 13.04 beta2 and am wondering how to setup deja-dup to synch directly the selected folders with the "[copy](https://www.copy.com/home/)" cloud service (and others).
Any idea?

I guess you have to use the custom location but have no clue about the address...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be possible to set the deja-dup backup directory as the 'copy' folder in /home/*username*/copy? Admittedly there's no way yet to automatically sync unless you download the copy app but apparently they're working on a .deb package.